# Symfony2: Use session object in Twig file

Tags: symfony, twig

> In Symfony2, how to access session object and check whether Session is set or
>   not from a twig file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty easy stuff.

You can access the session with this shortcut:

```
{{ app.session.get('key') }}
```

Also check for existence:

```
{{ app.session.has('key') }}
```